# LINQ: Filter the list according to the math condition above elements in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity list, where one of the fields (`UtcOffset`) is a number.

And I have a filter list `offsets` which is a list of numbers.

I want to select with a LINQ from the first list all the entities where the `UtcOffset` field is equal or less than to the values from the filter list with the fixed `delta` (3600) added.

I have a code that works for "equal-case" only

```
public class TimeZone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UtcOffset { get; set; }
}


var delta = 3600;

List<TimeZone> TimeZones = new List<TimeZone>()
{
    new TimeZone() {Id = 1, Name = "America/Tortola", UtcOffset = -14400},
    new TimeZone() {Id = 2, Name = "Asia/Kathmandu", UtcOffset = 20700},
    new TimeZone() {Id = 3, Name = "Asia/Kolkata", UtcOffset = 19800},
    new TimeZone() {Id = 4, Name = "Africa/Tunis", UtcOffset = 3600},
    new TimeZone() {Id = 5, Name = "Africa/Windhoek", UtcOffset = 7200},
    new TimeZone() {Id = 6, Name = "Europe/Simferopol", UtcOffset = 10800},
}

List<Int32> offsets = new List<Int32>()
{
    3600, -10800, -14400
};

var matchedList = TimeZones.Where(t => offsets.Contains(t.UtcOffset)).ToList();
```

It returns entities with ids 1 and 4.

I want to select entities with ids 1, 4, 5 (which have `UtcOffset` less or equal than 3600 + `delta`, -10800 + `delta`, -14400 + `delta`).

How I can modify my LINQ expression to match this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var delta = 3600;

        List<TimeZone> TimeZones = new List<TimeZone>()
        {
            new TimeZone() {Id = 1, Name = "America/Tortola", UtcOffset = -14400},
            new TimeZone() {Id = 2, Name = "Asia/Kathmandu", UtcOffset = 20700},
            new TimeZone() {Id = 3, Name = "Asia/Kolkata", UtcOffset = 19800},
            new TimeZone() {Id = 4, Name = "Africa/Tunis", UtcOffset = 3600},
            new TimeZone() {Id = 5, Name = "Africa/Windhoek", UtcOffset = 7200},
            new TimeZone() {Id = 6, Name = "Europe/Simferopol", UtcOffset = 10800},
        };

        List<Int32> offsets = new List<Int32>()
        {
            3600, -10800, -14400
        };

        var matchedList = TimeZones.Where(x => offsets.Any(y => x.UtcOffset <= (y + delta))).ToList();
    }
}

public class TimeZone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UtcOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoSalerno there is no point in looping through the offsets when you can just get and use the minvalue

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to work more efficiently, just use this (credits to @yawnobleix for spotting this, though it really needs to be `Max()` not `Min()`):

```
var matchedList = TimeZones.Where(t => t.UtcOffset <= (offsets.Max() + delta)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you should avoid editing the offsets directly also couldn't you just get the min value of the offsets? var minValue = offsets.Min() += delta; var matchedList = TimeZones.Where(t =>  t.UtcOffset <= minValue)).ToList();

Comment: It has the exact same result as your answer, @MarcoSalerno.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti you shouldn't change the values of the offsets each time

Comment: @yawnobleix, fair point. It should list all those with UtcOffset <= (-14400 + 3600)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, I believe if we were to benchmark the solutions on massive amounts of data, this solution would be faster. The ForEach loop was on purpose. But as yawnobleix pointed out, the minimum should win anyway.

Comment: @yawnobleix, actually the `.Max()` needs to be used not the `.Min()`. I've edited my answer above.